# Trouble Importing Microsoft CSV(Historical-Search) into powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

When I try to load the result of an Historical Search (through EAC) into my Powershell Script, I get whitespaces in the result between every letter. So for Example what looked in the original csv like

```
Header1, Header2, Header3,
Content1, Content2, Content3
```

Now Looks like

```
" H e a d e r 1 ", " H e a d e r 2 ", " H e a d e r 3 ",
" C o n t en t 1", ...
```

I already tried re-downloading the files and creating a datatable etc but nothing works because the data is just wrong.
When I open the csv in Editor, the whitespaces aren't there.

Select Statements also don't work.

BTW the same Thing works for the traditional message trace csv

```
$trace = Import-Csv W:\Path.csv
```

If anybody knows what might cause this, i would love to know the fix since it's driving me crazy

Update: I checked the csv on Notepad++ and These are not whtitespaces, but \0 values.
Any Ideas how they got there and why they are there?

Comment: Looks like you need to check what `-Encoding` to use for `Import-Csv`, try -Enoding Unicode

Comment: Thanks that did actually fix the Problem, Cheers mate!